# JavaScript checking if parameter exists but wrong value

Tags: javascript

I've wrong a JavaScript function that passes a value through but when I read the console.log() it shows `timeout: 70` when it should be `timeout: 0` and the `typeof` is a `number`

```
FancyPants(0);

function FancyPants(t) {
    console.log(typeof t);
    if (t) {
        var timeout = t;
    } else {
        var timeout = 70;
    }
    console.log('timeout: '+timeout);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

`0` is a falsy value:

```
> Boolean(0)
false
```

hence the condition is not fulfilled and the `else` branch is executed instead.

To accept `0`, use a more restrictive test:

```
if (typeof t === 'number') {
```

And I guess you don't want negative timeouts (also handles `NaN`) either:

```
if (typeof t === 'number' && t >= 0) {
```

Comment: What if I want to pass through a 0?

Comment: That's exactly what is handled by this code and the whole point of my answer.